# Strange syntax in an Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following code is intended to update an emp record.  However, if Zip is null, the data does not get updated.

I did not write this code, and I am not sure of the original intention behind using this type of syntax and I don't see a benefit to it.

Example: `zip = iif(zip<>@zip,@zip,zip)`

I would just write this: `zip = @zip`

Am I missing anything?

The intention is to update the zip field as long as the @zip parameter is not null.  The problem is that it does not get updated with the zip field currently is null.

```
UPDATE emp
SET first_name = iif(first_name <> @first_name,@first_name,first_name)
    ,last_name = iif(last_name <> @last_name, @last_name, last_name)
    ,dob = iif(dob <> @dob,@dob,dob)
    ,social_security_num = iif(social_security_num<>@social_security_num,@social_security_num,social_security_num)
    ,dl_num = iif(dl_num<>@dl_num,@dl_num,dl_num)
    ,dl_state = iif(dl_state<>@dl_state,@dl_state,dl_state)
    ,gender = iif(gender<>@gender,@gender,gender)
    ,address1 = iif(address1<>@address1,@address1,address1)
    ,address2 = iif(address2<>@address2,@address2,address2)
    ,city = iif(city<>@city,@city,city)
    ,zip = iif(zip<>@zip,@zip,zip)
    ,STATE = iif(state<>@state,@state,state)
    ,primary_phone = iif(primary_phone<>@primary_phone,@primary_phone,primary_phone)
    ,emergency_contact = iif(emergency_contact<>@emergency_contact,@emergency_contact,emergency_contact)
    ,secondary_phone = iif(secondary_phone<>@secondary_phone,@secondary_phone,secondary_phone)
    ,emergency_contact_phone = iif(emergency_contact_phone<>@emergency_contact_phone,@emergency_contact_phone,emergency_contact_phone)
    ,emp_pay_type_id = @emp_pay_type_id
WHERE emp_id = @emp_id
```

Comment: Looks like you may just need an IF ZIP IS NULL condition.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the `IIF` either, is the original writer available to ask why it was written this way? Perhaps it was generated code

Comment: NULLs seem to be the difference. in this case "zip = iif(zip<>@zip,@zip,zip)" if @zip is null, it wont update the zip to null, but "zip = @zip" it will. you could write it like - 
"zip = ISNULL(@zip, zip)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference: The column will never be updated to `null`.

Any comparison with `null` is not true (except for the special `IS NULL` expression), even if compared to another `null`.

The expression

```
iif(zip<>@zip,@zip,zip)
```

has the same effect as

```
case when @zip is null or zip is null then zip else @zip end
```

Note also that if the column is itself `null`, it will also never be updated.

Comment: So this would be the correct way to write it: `zip = iif(zip is null or zip<>@zip,@zip,zip)` ?

Comment: @greg that would depend on the intention. It makes sense to me as-is as a way of preventing columns from being nulled out, for example by a PATCH request. I have added a less obtuse equivalent expression to my answer.

Comment: @GregGum - the logic is symmetrical between the field and the variable. If either of them is `NULL` - nothing should happen.

Comment: The intention is to update the zip field as long as the @zip parameter is not null. The problem is that it does not get updated with the zip field currently is null.

Comment: @brian good point. `or zip is null` added to case condition.

Comment: @greg my guess is that this code expects the insert to guarantee non-null values for the columns, and this code keeps them not null. That is not the same as making the column not null to prevent nulls, which would throw an exception when a regular update to null was attempted, whereas this code silently "ignores" nulls.

Comment: You could of course change it around: `iif(zip=@zip, zip, @zip)`  This way `zip` will get updated if it is `NULL`, however, it will also get updated if the variable is `NULL`. And it seems you want to check both sides for `NULL`. I suppose `zip = COALESCE(@zip, zip)` would suit your needs: `zip` gets updated if `@zip` is not `NULL`, otherwise it keeps its value, regardless whether it is currently `NULL` or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically stating:
If the zip column does not equal zip, then the new value should be @zip (the variable) otherwise the new value should be the existing value.

Your method is not making a comparison and just setting it to the variable.

Both should output the same result, unless the variable is null. This will cause a short circuit and the IF will be FALSE, and the current value will be retained.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (zip NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @table (zip) VALUES ('90210-1234')

DECLARE @zip NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT * 
  FROM @table

UPDATE @table
   SET zip = IIF(@zip<>zip,@zip,zip)

SELECT * 
  FROM @table

UPDATE @table
   SET zip = @zip

SELECT * 
  FROM @table

SET @zip = '90210-1234'

UPDATE @table
   SET zip = @zip

SELECT * 
  FROM @table
```

```
zip
---
90210-1234  --Original Value

zip
---
90210-1234  --Not updated because of short circuit

zip
---
NULL        --Set to NULL as the variable was NULL

zip
---
90210-1234  --Set to a value
```